# Unable to send/receive messages in Multi Node Kafka cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have a multi node kafka cluster, im able to create the topics 
successfully, which is clear in the zookeeper logs. But i cant send/receive messages from some of the topics even though they are created.

Also i dont see the logs created for the topics for some of them in the /tmp/kafka-logs directory in any of the kafka brokers that are part of the 3 nodes.

For example: If i had created Topic1...Topic5. I'm able to send and receive messages for topic3,topic4. I have my producer & consumer running in node1.
Any idea if I'm doing anything wrong here?

On the producer side:

```
private Properties producerConfig() {
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", "host1:9092,host2:9092,host3:9092");
  props.put("acks", "all");
  props.put("retries", 0);
  props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
  props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

return props;
}
```

On Consumer side:

```
     private Properties createConsumerConfig(String zookeeper, String groupId) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("zookeeper.connect", "host1:2181,host2:2181,host3:2181");
        props.put("group.id", groupId);
        props.put("auto.commit.enable", "false");
        props.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");

        return props;
      }
```

Multi Node cluster Setup:

I have used the following instructions to setup the multi node cluster.

```
Host1 :: zk1,kafkabroker1
Host2 :: zk2,kafkabroker2
Host3 :: zk3,kafkabroker3
```

https://itblog.adrian.citu.name/2014/01/30/how-to-set-an-apache-kafka-multi-node-multi-broker-cluster/

Comment: Do you see any error message on the logs?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thanks for taking a look, I'm using the confluent platform. I dont get any error in kafka/zookeeper// In fact, if i try to list the topics in all the three zk nodes, im able to see the topics that i created dynamically is available..  I'm wondering if i should juist the broker info in the properties in the consumer side instead of specifying zk nodes..

Comment: If there is no error in the logs, and you double checked the host, zk, and topic names, I have no idea what might be the problem right now... sorry.

Comment: i see these.. [2016-07-27 22:32:45,922] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1562e20e7a80000 type:create cxid:0x18 zxid:0x50000005d txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers/group/owners/Tic1 Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /consumers/group/owners/Tic1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)

Comment: Does this cause any issue..

Comment: It's an INFO message. No ERROR. Thus, I doubt it.